# TableViewCell Design With Own Nib and Subclass of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have subclassed `UITableViewCell` as `MyCell` and am attempting to get the table to show. I always receive the message:

`exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

The code for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
MyCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
// Configure the cell...
MyCell* theCell = (MyCell *)cell;
UILabel* lab = theCell.theLabel;
lab.text = @"This is the label text";
return cell;
}
```

I have set the CellIdentifier as "Cell" in the  nib. I thought I was returning a cell with the last line?
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is the MyCell subclass inheriting UITableViewCell?

Comment: Something in the second line of your code is not correct...

Comment: Thanks, deleted the second line. Was an error.

Comment: MyCell is subclass inheriting UITableViewCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cell must be nil. You should white something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MyCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell"].lastObject;
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    UILabel* lab = cell.theLabel;
    lab.text = @"This is the label text";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is likely the case. Note that the exception to this is if you are using `Storyboards`, which should create a cell for you (as long as you have the identifier setup correctly, I believe).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I forgot to load the nib and there was no cell available to return.